# .htaccess RewriteRule/RedirectMatch to add trailing slash, doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two websites, one is for development and one is for testing. They are both subdirectories / subdomains on a VPS.

I have an identical .htaccess file on each of them, to add a trailing slash via 301 redirect, namely:

```
RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch 301 /dm/secure/([^/]+)$ /dm/secure/$1/
```

On the development site, when I visit a URL without the trailing slash, e.g. `https://reports-dev.example.com/dm/secure/Client`, it redirects me to
`https://reports-dev.example.com/home/example/public_html/reports-dev/dm/secure/Client/`

On the testing site, it has no effect -- e.g. visiting `https://reports-test.example.com/dm/secure/Client` stays put (and gets a 404).

I've also tried:
- using `RewriteBase /` and `RewriteBase /dm/` and `RewriteBase /dm/secure`
- using `RewriteRule /dm/secure/([^/]+)$ /dm/secure/$1/ [R=301,L]`

No change in results.

I'm a little upset that it's not working properly, but what's much more concerning is that it behaves differently between the dev and test sites.

There is a .htaccess one level up in public_html, but it doesn't refer to either site.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to note is the `[R=301]`. That causes a permanent redirect, which browsers cache and remember, without making any request to the webserver. So the current contents of the .htaccess file are irrelevant -- what's only relevant is what's in the browser's cache..

Moral of the story: Don't use 301 redirects during development.